# Can a state's parole board restrict someone from the ability to see their own children using a condition of no contact with minors?

Tags: united-states, ohio

This would be in Ohio. Does a restriction of "no contact with minors" apply to your own children?

Comment: I would hope so... Why should a person's own children be less protected from the parent if the state considers that person to be a danger to children?

Comment: @brhans I'm not sure about Ohio in particular, but people can get added to the Sex Offenders Register for things like public nudity that wouldn't put their own children at any particular risk, even if it might ban them from employment involving working with children.

Comment: The difference is that i never had a right to see my neighbours children, for example, even though there is nothing preventing me. For their own children, someone might have a right to see them with supervision.